# How to explain using browser.sleep in protractor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm a new to protractor,and I'm trying to test popover event,
here is my code:

```
    describe('popover directive', function() {
        var buttons= element.all(by.tagName('button'));

        it('should show the popover title by clicking', function() {
            var popTitle="testTitle";               
            var popContent="testContent";                   

            element(by.model('title')).clear().sendKeys(popTitle);     
            element(by.model('content')).clear().sendKeys(popContent).then(function(){
                 buttons.get(0).click().then(function(){
                     browser.sleep(1000);
                     expect(element(by.className('popover-title')).getText()).toMatch(popTitle);                
                     expect(element(by.className('popover-content')).getText()).toMatch(popContent);
                 });    
             });                    
            buttons.get(0).click(); 
            browser.sleep(1000);      
            expect(element(by.css('[class="popover fade top in"]')).isPresent()).toBe(false);      
        });
    });
```

1.If I don't add delay time code like `browser.sleep()`, the test will fail and show a message:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.className('popover-title')
```

Is that possible not to add delay time code ...like `browser.sleep()`? If that is impossible, how to make sense to set the sleep time well? Is that have some connection with CSS animations? 
2.Using `browser.waitForAngular()` or `click().then(function(){...})` instead of `browser.sleep()` seems no work, will get the same error message.

That would be great if someone can answer these questions, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that you had to add a sleep is likely because of your animation. Many animations use `setTimeout`, which Angular (thus Protractor) does not know about and do not wait for. The angular equivalent to `setTimeout` is its `$timeout` service.

But often you cannot change the animation library to stop using `setTimeout`. To work with this in protractor, use `browser.wait` with a timeout (not sleep).

```
buttons.get(0).click(); 

browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by.css('[class="popover fade top in"]')).isPresent().then(function(present) {
    return !present;
  });
  // or by checking any other element to know that the animation completed
}, 1000);

expect(element(by.css('[class="popover fade top in"]')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

With Protractor 1.7, you will be able to use the expectedConditions library so you can do this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
buttons.get(0).click(); 

var e = element(by.css('[class="popover fade top in"]'));
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.presenceOf(e)), 1000);

expect(e.isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

Comment: thank you @hankduan . This answer helps me to figure it out finally, and just can't wait to see Protractor 1.7 !

Comment: I have used above one but noticed that the element is not present in the wait block of code.How to check if animation is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using browser, declare a protractor instance :

```
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
  ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Then use:

```
ptor.get
```

instead of browser.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not just want to instead of "browser" by ptor, I really want to remove "browser.sleep()" from my code.

Comment: ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true; will alow you to do so

Comment: Using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` will not allow you to magically remove sleep statement. That statement's only purpose is if you are working with a non-angular app, and you should **never** have to add it for angular apps.

Comment: Why? So many things in angular/protractor are just "do it this way its better" without any explanation, it's quite maddening. I've never seen a group of technologies so hostile to new users in all my life.